# Postgres functions - parameter efficiency

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-aurora

I am trying to find out some information regarding Postgres parameters relating to performance.
With a microservice approach, we will be collecting external data (to the postgres db) and passing this data into function paramters in code. Now we can either pass the data in as a json object, or a custom type.

What I want to find out is are there any typical performance issues via either method, specifically which is the best way to go to get the best performance.

Using AWS Aurora Postgres v15

Comment: json will be slower, but you have to measure if you can really see the difference. 0.001 millisecond is twice as fast 0.002 millisecond, but does it matter? The downside of json is the lack of a schema. Any content is allowed, when you expect a date and you get 'abc', you have to handle that inside your function.